# decode form-urlencoded to hash

Tags: perl, lwp

The response I get to an LWP request is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is it possible convert the text of this to a hash via some object method?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
# from a HTTP::Response object
my $urlencoded = $response->content;
```

1. [`Vars` in `CGI`](http://p3rl.org/CGI#FETCHING-THE-PARAMETER-LIST-AS-A-HASH:) returns a hash.

   ```
   use CGI qw();
   CGI->new($urlencoded)->Vars;
   ```
2. [`parameters` in `Plack::Request`](http://p3rl.org/Plack::Request) returns a [`Hash::MultiValue`](http://p3rl.org/Hash::MultiValue) object, which is actually the appropriate data structure for this.

   ```
   use Plack::Request qw();
   Plack::Request->new({QUERY_STRING => $urlencoded})->parameters;
   ```
3. [`param` in `APR::Request`/`libapreq2`](http://p3rl.org/APR::Request#param) - not quite a Perl hash, but an XS object with attached Magic whose behaviour is close enough.

   ```
   insert hand-waving here, no libapreq2 available right now for testing
   ```
4. [`url_params_mixed` in `URL::Encode`](http://p3rl.org/URL::Encode)

   ```
   require URL::Encode::XS;
   use URL::Encode qw(url_params_mixed);
   url_params_mixed $urlencoded;
   ```
5. [`parse_query_string` in `CGI::Deurl::XS`](http://p3rl.org/CGI::Deurl::XS)

   ```
   use CGI::Deurl::XS 'parse_query_string';
   parse_query_string $urlencoded;
   ```
6. [`query_form` in `URI`](http://p3rl.org/URI) serves well, too, in a pinch; and so does [`query_form_hash` in `URI::QueryParam`](http://p3rl.org/URI::QueryParam).

   ```
   use URI qw();
   URI->new("?$urlencoded")->query_form;

   use URI::QueryParam qw();
   URI->new("?$urlencoded")->query_form_hash;
   ```
7. Bonus: also see [`HTTP::Body::UrlEncoded`](http://p3rl.org/HTTP::Body::UrlEncoded), as used by [Catalyst](http://catalyst.perl.org).

Comment: though I'm not sure about the last, the problem with these is that they mostly seem to be decoding a request if I'm not mistaken, I'm trying to decode a response.

Comment: Edited: Munging a HTTP response body into a HTTP request body is trivial, as you can see.

Comment: yeah, I was just having trouble finding the right methods/syntax. Probably going to use URI since it should already be loaded.